# TypeScript not erring when Redux's state types are wrong

Tags: typescript, redux

Im using TypeScript with React / Redux. Im trying to add types to my Redux state. I know that `foo` will be null or a number. However when I made it a string as a test it didn't error:

// This is correct

```
type State = {
  foo: number;
};

function reducers(state = initialState, action): State {
  //
}
```

// This is wrong

```
type State = {
  foo: string;
};

function reducers(state = initialState, action): State {
  //
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? The code you provided is working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you were expecting the error, but I would recommend adding the `State` type to the input as well since the first argument should also follow that type (and the `initialState`).

Here is a full example:

```js
type State = {
  foo: string;
};

const initialState: State = {
  foo: "bar"
}

function reducers(state: State = initialState, action: { type: string }): State {
  return state;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8CwAoKUBmA9gQFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gNzYC+zW2AxgbRVHdWDV4AGziIIpcUiipMOfEVIAiAEbxKy1tmx4ArrU5CeUShAAmezhEpkAFBQlSEM1AKGjpEADRR4R6h5SNChQSFIKGgYoFgBKZwl0bFwzYD1KWnIXCHYWIA)

And now changing `foo` will cause the `initialState` to error but the reducer itself won't since the input `state` matches the output of type `State`.

```js
type State = {
  foo: number; // <- changed to number
};

const initialState: State = {
  foo: "bar" // <- Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
}

function reducers(state: State = initialState, action: { type: string }): State {
  return state;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8CwAoKUBmA9gQFxQB2ArgLYBGEATgNxQD0LUAPALRQDGAFvDIBzCABMowAuWp162AL6Ns2XgTIBnYFACWZHcB3wANnEQRSZpFFSYc+IqQBENePSet23KABVw0AHItej1hAN0NcgJteA0NHWEyeBpjaClJfygAyloGAIA6RRUsPAoyXkN1KHpxCl4GDQAKLXNLBGtUPQMjU3aIABooeAqddVI0DMhSYNCoBQBKNvN0bFwa4Ap6MigWpGUsBSA)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness - `initialState` doesn't have to be typed. The mistyped property will be then catched in the `reducers()` function.

Comment: Correct, and I find it beneficial to keep type errors as close to the source as possible which is why I suggested explicitly typing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Reducer` export from `redux` whose type arguments are `<State, Actions>`, use that.